# Apache module mod_ext_filter does not filter output as expected

Tags: apache, sed

First some context :

I have several sites running Wordpress for which I want to be able to define a restrictive CSP, using nonce to allow inline scripts (WordPress plugins are nightmarish when it comes to plugin loading and a gazillion don't use the wp_enqueue_script, so you can't use a WordPress filter to do that at that level, pity because it can be done for properly enqueued scripts)

In order to do that I want to replace all '<script....>' tags with '<script nonce="12345ABCDE" ...>, a thing that I obviously cannot do by modifying each and every plugin that calls puts a script in the page.

I explored several possible solutions and while I can add the nonce, adding it before the DOM is loaded is where the rub is (after the DOM is loaded, it's too late the CSP wont allow execution because the nonce was not present at parsing time).

In the end I found something that might work by using Apache mod_ext_filter and another Apache module called cspnonce.

mod_cspnonce produces a nonce that it places ins a CSP_NONCE apache server variable, you just need to compile it and load it into your apache, works like a charm.

so I activated the Apache ext_filter module (and doubled checked that is was activated) after restarting my apache, then I created the filter:

```
<IfModule mod_ext_filter.c>
  ExtFilterDefine nonceadder intype=text/html mode=output \
  cmd="/bin/sed 's/script/script nonce=\"'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e'\"\ /g'"
</IfModule>
```

then added the output to the Directory directive:

```
<Directory /var/www/path/to/my/site>
   Require all granted
   AllowOverride All
   Options -Indexes +Followsymlinks

   SetOutputFilter nonceadder

</Directory>
```

(I also tied to set sit in a)

```
<Location "/">
       SetOutputFilter nonceadder
</Location>
```

with the same result)
I tested the sed command itself with a fixed value for the CSP_NONCE on a terminal and is does what I want

restarted my Apache. and there... nothing. The filter is not executed, there is no apparent filtering taking place. (i tried with other sed coomands such as 's/a/o/g' just to test that it was the sed that wasn't executed.

Path of the sed command is right, (I've see others having problem with that, this is not the case here
apache2ctl -M produces the list of the following modules (ext_filter is there):

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cspnonce_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

version details :
Ubuntu 18.04.5
Apache 2.4.46

So what did I forget ? What am I doing wrong ? I really am at a loss there any help would be welcome

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: No, I didn't (else I would have posted the solution, I hate unanswered questions on stack or question answered with 'Oh ok I fixed it', without other details :)). In this instance I gave up though. I Couldn't find anything in the apache logs related to the filter attempt, and the execution did not happen. Obviously this is a niche question, so it never got any attention too. I'd love a solution though. That would really help on future WP sites where I must tighten security.

Comment: @eric If you are still interested, and benefit of others like me who struggled for a few hours, I suggest you to temporarily add "LogLevel trace8" and then check Apache error logs. I successfully diagnosed and managed to run Perl based ext filter for my own application by studying the logs. mod_ext is too forgiving and not too helpful if you have made any typos in name of filter or cmd path. Hints (i) check path of "sed" on your Linux distro, (ii) remove intype=text/html and see if filtering gets applied, (iii) check error log, (iv) try a wrapper suggested by Ankit

Answer (score 0):

I tried your approach with small improvisation. Rather than using substitute, I tried php filter script through a file and made replacement in there.

```
<IfModule mod_ext_filter.c>
  ExtFilterDefine nonceadder intype=text/html mode=output \
  cmd="/usr/bin/php7.3 /etc/apache2/sites-available/filter.php > /dev/null 2>&1"
</IfModule>
```

There you can get nonce from $_SERVER.

```
<?php
    $nonce = $_SERVER['CSP_NONCE'];
    $f = fopen( 'php://stdin', 'r' );
    
    while( $line = fgets( $f ) ) {    
        $line = preg_replace( '%<script%', '<script nonce="'.$nonce.'"', $line );
        $line = preg_replace( '%<style%', '<style nonce="'.$nonce.'"', $line );
        $line = preg_replace( '%style="%', 'nonce="'.$nonce.'" style="', $line );
        echo $line;
    }   
    fclose( $f );
?>
```

I hope this will help you out.

Thanks

Ankit

Comment: You mean you're running the filter with that php on the file being served by apache ? Could you show the php code ?

Comment: I've updated answer. I hope this will help you out